# How to hide output pip calls in python

Tags: pip, python-3.9

How can I hide the output of this command as I have installed all the modules?

```
import pip
pip.main(["install", "pyttsx3"])
pip.main(["install", "SpeechRecognition"])
```

I want to remove all the output of the above code for my project as it shows a lot of multiple line output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `--quiet` option according to the [documentation](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/cli/pip/#console-logging):

```
pip.main(["install", "requests", "--quiet"])
```